# CSS3 selector for radio box group labels with no selection (non checked)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know you can select a label for checked input elements

```
<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad" value="1">
<label for="rad1">
    <div>Radio 1</div>
</label>
```

by selecting

```
input:checked {...}
```

However is there any selector to select all label element of a radio-box group if were is not any radio of the group selection yet? e.g

```
input:noselection { color: red; }
```

Example: none radio selected yet: all elements are black; as soon as one element get selected, this radio becomes green and all others grey.

I could add some js like following to add a class to the wrapping div and do a selection on it, however i was wondering  whether there is any native css3 selector for this.

```
$("fieldset :radio").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").addClass("answered"));
});
```

Comment: Just use `input {...}` before the `input:checked {}` line?

Comment: Odd that it doesn't appear that's supported, though I've never asked it.  However, as DavidG was alluding to, if you apply something to all inputs and then apply something to all checked inputs, you have the difference of the set and can affect only the unchecked (i.e. undoing that on the checked).

Comment: While there is `:not()` to reverse `:checked`, this works only on a single input field; there is no selector (or combination thereof) for “if all radio buttons in a group are unchecked” – you will have to use JavaScript for that kind of logic.

Answer (score 1):

If this radio button group is required (via the `required` attribute), then assuming browser compatibility is not an issue (if only because I'm unsure of how well it is supported) the `:invalid` selector is what you're looking for:

```
input[name="rad"]:invalid ~ label {...}
```

If this radio button group is *not* required, then you might be in quite a fix. Since there is no selector that represents an empty or unselected field regardless of its required state, I can't think of a way other than to explicitly list every non-checked input, and that requires a structure that can be represented with a selector, which I can't determine from the limited markup that you have given (but if each of your labels directly follows its input then this isn't possible).

Comment: this works as long as required. However my answers are nor required :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `input:not(:checked) + label`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6Fv5w/)**

**EDIT :**

As @BoltClock mentioned, this solution doesn't work for if you don't select the first checkbox. The only solution I can think of would be to use JS for the behaviour you are looking for.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6Fv5w/4/)**

*CSS :*

```
input + label div{
    color:black;
}

input:checked ~ label div{
    color:grey;    
}

input:checked + label div{
    color:green;    
}
```

Comment: But check one of the inputs and the style remains on labels of unchecked inputs. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @BoltClock I think the OP wants to select all labels of unchecked inputs doesn't he?

Comment: The important part: "a radio-box group which has no selection at all"

Comment: @BoltClock I undesrtand now more info has been added, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @BoltClock is right, I added an example to the question for clarification.

Comment: Selecting the last checkbox still fails to affect preceding labels in the same radio group, mainly due to a limitation of the `~` combinator. I still think this can only be made possible with some modifications to the HTML.

Comment: @BoltClock ah, I've got to keep on searching then

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not` pseudo-selector.

```
input:not(:checked){ color: red; }
```